# Check Bitbucket credentials by OAuth 2.0 keys

Tags: bash, shell, oauth-2.0, bitbucket

I've created a OAuth key inside Bitbucket and want to replace my current shell/bash function to check if my username and password is correct. This function returned a HTTP response code.

How I can do this with the Bitbucket OAuth Keys? I've tried to replace the $USERNAME and $PASSWORD for the keys but it doesn't work.

```
  http_status=$(curl -X HEAD -s -w '%{http_code}' \
  -u "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/$repo_owner)
```

Comment: "doesn't work" in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to [use an `Authorization` header](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/concepts/oauth2.html) instead of the `-u` parameter:

```
http_status=$(curl -X HEAD -s -w '%{http_code}' \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer <OAUTH_TOKEN_GOES_HERE>" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/$repo_owner)
```

If you don't have a token yet you'll have to request one, e.g.

> Request authorization from the end user by sending their browser to:
>
> ```
> https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code
> ```
>
> The callback includes the `?code={}` query parameter that you can swap
>   for an access token:
>
> ```
> curl -X POST -u "client_id:secret" \
>     https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \
>     -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code={code}
> ```

Comment: When I used the code to request a code, I got this error: `{"error_description": "The specified code is not valid.", "error": "invalid_grant"}`

Comment: @CodeWhisperer, I've updated my answer. I missed part of the instructions before. The link includes information about several different flows; if this one doesn't fit your needs feel free to try another.

Comment: how can I get the "access_toke" from the json values?

Comment: @CodeWhisperer, I don't have an application registered and I can't find a sample response to that endpoint. I would think the `access_token` should be easy to find in the response. Can you provide a sample (with anything sensitive redacted, of course)?

Comment: This is the Json response `{access_token: sdhsjh87sd8sdhjsdhsdgsd=, scopes: repository:delete repository:admin repository:write project:write team:write account:write, expires_in: 3600, refresh_token: ajhsdjhdUJDHjs, token_type: bearer}`

Comment: @CodeWhisperer, does the `access_token` value inside that object not work? (Aside: Please avoid pasting actual token values; they should be protected as passwords. In this case it looks like the token will already have expired by now.)

Comment: that's not a working token. I've added some random characters to it beqouse I know that it must be private :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151984/discussion-between-chris-and-codewhisperer).